# Location permission only for the ad platforms: Is it worth it?

Tags: android, admob

I'm considering add location permissions to my app (Android) in order to pass that location to the ad platforms (currently Admob and Mobfox). But I don't want to make it if it doesn't worth it because ask for location in my app have not sense from the point of view of the user.

Does someone have tested how the location affect on the CRT, eCPM ...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, most users don't know what permissions are, what they mean, and just click their way to the download as fast as they can. You could ask the permission to empty their bank account and date their wives and they wouldn't read it.

Of course there are exceptions but so few.

Answer (score 1):

It's against AdMob's terms of service to provide location information if the application itself does not use location.  So I would recommend that you don't add the permission only to pass the location to the ad networks.

Answer (score 1):

People are going to complain about it in the comments, I would suggest explaining any permissions in the App Description field.

Answer (score 1):

Is it for their own record purposes or for the ad server?

If it's the first case: You should tell them your concerns, or if you can judge from the website traffic, give them some estimate like "70% US, 20% UK, 10% India."

If it's the second: It could hurt your fill rate if they are supposed to give you ads for an US category but the users are all in Brazil and then it will affect the CTR and eCPM.